# Federated Identity segregation using external Identity Providers

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, identity, federated-identity, azure-ad-b2b

We're trying to set up a central platform to assign groups to users coming from several organizations.

Each organization has its own identity provider, which we require supports SAML. Using SAML, we authenticate these users onto our platform in an isolated environment, i.e. users from one org should not be able to see users from another.

We were hoping to use Azure AD for this task and its Administrative Unit feature. Administrative Units proved ineffective though, as they don't allow this segregation. Either a users sees all users/groups in the AD, or none at all.

We also cannot use multiple Azure tenants, since we need to map these users onto AWS SSO, which only supports one tenant.

Are you aware of another identity service which allows SAML federated identity and org isolation?

Comment: checkout https://www.datawiza.com/platform/. It talks to multiple identity providers on behalf your apps.

Comment: Hi @barmanthewise, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0):

•   You can surely configure federated identity segregation and isolation using SAML with Azure AD by leveraging its various features like **User based access control (RBAC or Roles Based Access Control) with authentication and identity separation, security assurances for processes and practices using Security Development Lifecycle, Identity based isolation, zero trust architecture, Azure Active Directory, Data encryption, key vault**, and many others. The concept for user-based access control can be illustrated through the diagram below. Also, `multi-tenancy in the public cloud improves efficiency by multiplexing resources among disparate customers at low cost; however, this approach introduces the perceived risk associated with resource sharing. Azure addresses this risk by providing a trustworthy foundation for isolated cloud services using a multi-layered approach` depicted in figure below: -

[image: Identity Isolation]

•   Also, do take into consideration that tenant isolation in Azure AD involves two primary elements: -

a)  **Preventing data leakage and access across tenants, which means that data belonging to Tenant A can't in any way be obtained by users in Tenant B without explicit authorization by Tenant A**.

b)  **Resource access isolation across tenants, which means that operations performed by Tenant A can't in any way impact access to resources for Tenant B**.

`Access via Azure AD requires user authentication through a Security Token Service (STS). The authorization system uses information on the user’s existence and enabled state through the Directory Services API and Azure RBAC to determine whether the requested access to the target Azure AD instance is authorized for the user in the session`. From the below figure, you can illustrate that Aside from token-based authentication that is tied directly to the user, Azure AD further supports logical isolation in Azure through: -

[image: Azure AD token authentication]

a)  **Azure AD instances are discrete containers and there's no relationship between them**.

b)  **Azure AD data is stored in partitions and each partition has a pre-determined set of replicas that are considered the preferred primary replicas. Use of replicas provides high availability of Azure AD services to support identity separation and logical isolation**.

c)  **Access isn't permitted across Azure AD instances unless the Azure AD instance administrator grants it through federation or provisioning of user accounts from other Azure AD instances**.

d)  **Physical access to servers that comprise the Azure AD service and direct access to Azure AD’s back-end systems is restricted to properly authorized Microsoft operational roles using the Just-In-Time (JIT) privileged access management system**.

e)  **Azure AD users have no access to physical assets or locations, and therefore it isn't possible for them to bypass the logical Azure RBAC policy checks**.

For more information regarding the above, kindly refer to the documentation link below: -

https://aka.ms/AADDataWhitePaper

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview